How could I increase minimal range in mat-slider element of Angular framework
I'm using Angular v16. I'm creating a range slider using mat-slider element. By default, the logic is that maximal value cannot be lower than minimal value, but they can be equal, so minimal range possible is 0. How could I change or set that minimal range, meaning that range should be for example 10 or more and maximal and minimal values cannot be equal ?
I've checked Angular v16 documentation, but I don't found anything related to this topic (might as well missed something).

You can use custom validation, to perform any business logic checks you need.
export default function RangeValidator(
  control: AbstractControl
): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const form = control as FormGroup;
  const left = form.get('start')?.value || 0;
  const right = form.get('end')?.value || 0;
  console.log(left, right);
  return left !== right && right - left > 10
    ? null
    : {
        rangeError: true,
      };
}

Now, we apply this validation on the formGroup that contains the slider.
form = new FormGroup({
  slider: new FormGroup(
    {
      start: new FormControl(0),
      end: new FormControl(10),
    },
    [RangeValidator] // <- custom validator
  ),
});

In the HTML, we add a validation message, that gets shown when the error rangeError is present.
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-slider min="0" max="100" formGroupName="slider">
    <input matSliderStartThumb formControlName="start" />
    <input matSliderEndThumb formControlName="end" />
  </mat-slider>
  <br />
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('slider')?.errors?.rangeError">
    Range has to be greater than 10.</mat-error
  >
</form>

For changing the color of the slider when invalid, we use mat.slider-color, to change it to invalid color.
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import '../styles.scss';

::ng-deep mat-slider.ng-invalid {
  @include mat.slider-color($theme, $color-variant: error);
}

Stackblitz Demo

Two mat-slider elements are used to represent the minimum and maximum values.
adjusts the maximum value if the range becomes too small when the minimum value changes and vice versa.
slider.component.html
<div>
  <mat-slider
    min="0"
    max="100"
    step="1"
    value="{{minValue}}"
    (input)="onMinInput($event)"
    thumbLabel
  ></mat-slider>
  <mat-slider
    min="0"
    max="100"
    step="1"
    value="{{maxValue}}"
    (input)="onMaxInput($event)"
    thumbLabel
  ></mat-slider>
</div>

slider.component.ts
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-slider',
      templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
    })
    export class SliderComponent {
      minValue = 0;
      maxValue = 100;
      minRange = 10; // Set your minimum range value here
    
      onMinInput(event: any): void {
        const newMinValue = event.value;
        if (this.maxValue - newMinValue < this.minRange) {
          this.maxValue = newMinValue + this.minRange;
        }
        this.minValue = newMinValue;
      }
    
      onMaxInput(event: any): void {
        const newMaxValue = event.value;
        if (newMaxValue - this.minValue < this.minRange) {
          this.minValue = newMaxValue - this.minRange;
        }
        this.maxValue = newMaxValue;
      }
    }

